# Evaluate the double integral $\int\int_R(x^2-2y) $ $dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the double integral $\int\int_R(x^2-2y) $ $dxdy$, where $R$ is a region bounded by $y=kx$, $y=(kx)^3$, $x \geq 0$, and $k$ is a fixed positive constant. (The answer will depend on $k$.)

I have completed this question but it doesn't match up with the solution I have been given.

My solution, where the region is
$R = \{ (x,y) : \frac{y}{k}\leq x \leq \frac{\sqrt[3]{y}}{k}, 0\leq y \leq k \}$

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{k}\int_{\frac{y}{k}}^{\frac{\sqrt[3]{y}}{k}}(x^2+2y) dxdy &= \int_{0}^{k}\bigg[\frac{x^3}{3}+2yx\bigg]_\frac{y}{k}^\frac{\sqrt[3]{y}}{k} dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{k}\frac{y-y^3}{3k^3}+\frac{2y\sqrt[3]{y}-2y^2}{k}dy \\
&= \bigg[\frac{y^2}{6k^3}-\frac{y^4}{12k^3}+\frac{6y^\frac{7}{3}}{7k}-\frac{y^2}{k}\bigg]_0^k \\
&= \frac{1}{6k}-\frac{k}{12}+\frac{6k^\frac{4}{3}}{7}-k
\end{align}

Comment: Did you graph the region? What is the answer given?

Comment: can't say I have graphed it. The question is multiple choice so they have given 4 answers to choose from. 

1. $\frac{2}{21k}+\frac{1}{10k^3}$

2. $\frac{4}{21k}+\frac{1}{12k^3}$

3. $\frac{5}{21k}+\frac{1}{15k^3}$

4. $\frac{1}{21k}+\frac{1}{15k^3}$

Comment: Between $x = 0$ and $x = 1/k$, $kx \ge (kx)^{3}$ and for $x >1/k$, $(kx)^{3} > kx$. This is important for your region $R$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of integration. I get
$$\int_{x=0}^{1/k}\int_{y=(kx)^3}^{kx}(x^2-2y)\; dy\; dx =
\frac{1}{12k^3}-\frac{4}{21k}$$

---

Note that the curves intersect when
$$0=(kx)^3-(kx) = (kx)((kx)^2-1)=(kx)(kx+1)(kx-1)$$
so when $x=0$ or $x=\pm1/k$. In the right half-plane, then, the bounded region is between $x=0$ and $x=1/k$.

---

None of the answers given is correct. I would say they intend the second answer, since it is nearly correct but with a sign error in the first term.